# elastic4s org.elasticsearch.client.transport.NoNodeAvailableException:

Tags: scala, elasticsearch, elastic4s

I'm having issues connecting to a local version of elasticsearch. I'm doing the following

```
val uri = ElasticsearchClientUri("elasticsearch://127.0.0.1:9300")
val client = ElasticClient.remote(uri)
lient execute { search in "_all" query "test" }
```

But get a

```
org.elasticsearch.client.transport.NoNodeAvailableException: None of the    configured nodes are available: []
```

exception. It doesn't matter if I go between 9200 / or 9300. ES is up and running correctly as far as I can see. Any pointers appreciated.

Comment: Hello Steve, can you check this link: https://github.com/sksamuel/elastic4s See if it helps you.

Comment: how come you are using remote with local address? Can you hit your local instance at 9200 with basic GET request to  see it s responding?

Comment: I was able to connect to my local instance with just ```val client = ElasticClient.local```

Comment: What is the versions of client and server? They can be inconpetible.

Comment: Hi @AkshayBijawe thanks for the comment - I've been basing the examples off of that and a few other derivatives but none worked :-(

Comment: @alpert that was it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some possible reasons for this:

- The client and server versions can be different
- Cluster name can be different
- There could be a network problem when accesing the host and port.

Answer (score 0):

In your local ElasticSearch instance, have you modified cluster.name in elasticsearch.yml? In that case you need to build `Settings` object.

```
val settings = Settings.settingsBuilder().put("cluster.name", "cluster_name").build()    // set cluster_name to cluster.name from your elasticsearch.yml
val uri = ElasticsearchClientUri("elasticsearch://127.0.0.1:9300")
client = ElasticClient.remote(settings, uri)
```

Answer (score -1):

**How to create elasticsearch 2.4.0 transport client using scala?**

```
import com.sksamuel.elastic4s.ElasticDsl._
import com.sksamuel.elastic4s.{ElasticsearchClientUri, ElasticClient}
import org.elasticsearch.common.settings.Settings    
object Facebook {
        def main(args: Array[String]) {


    val settings = Settings.builder().put("cluster.name", "myClusterName").build()
    val client = ElasticClient.transport(settings, ElasticsearchClientUri("elasticsearch://localhost:9300"))
          client.execute { createIndex("places") shards 3 replicas 2 }
        }
    }
```

**scala maven dependencies:**

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sksamuel.elastic4s</groupId>
        <artifactId>elastic4s-core_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sksamuel.elastic4s</groupId>
        <artifactId>elastic4s-tcp_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
        <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

**output Result:**

```
    log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.elasticsearch.plugins).
    log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
    log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: LUCENE_4_0_0
        at org.elasticsearch.Version.<clinit>(Version.java:44)
        at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient$Builder.build(TransportClient.java:129)
        at com.sksamuel.elastic4s.ElasticClient$.transport(ElasticClient.scala:112)
        at example.Facebook$.main(Facebook.scala:23)
        at example.Facebook.main(Facebook.scala)
```